# How to force IAR linker to keep unused functions?

Tags: c, linker, iar, dead-code

I'm testing a C software written for Renesas RL78 microcontroller. The software is still in development, so there are functions which are implemented but not yet called. As a result, such functions are eliminated by the linker, which outputs the following entries in the listing:

```
CODE
  Segment part 42. NOT NEEDED.
       LOCAL                   ADDRESS         
       =====                   =======         
       function_name
```

My goal is to perform unit tests of these functions on the target system, so I need the code to be present in the output ELF file. How can I tell the linker to keep the unused functions? I already tried to set optimization level to *None*, and set module type to both *Program* or *Library*. I have also defined a single code segment called `CODE`. All these actions had no desired effect on the linker output.

I can't modify the source code (technically, I can modify all I want, but I can't commit anything), so calling all the functions I need from `main()` is not an option.

Comment: How are you planning to unit test functions that are never called

Comment: @M.M by creating a stack frame and placing the entry point address into program counter.

Comment: @M.M I have added a screenshot to my answer to give you an idea how this is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the relevant [tech note](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/linker/the-linker-removing-functions-and-variables-or-external-not-found/) which suggests the following:

> - IAR XLINK Linker -g option
> - IAR ILINK Linker --keep option
> - use the REQUIRE keyword in assembler
> - use the __root extension keyword

Since I use `xlink`, I tried out the first option and it worked. Here's the option quick reference:

```
-gsymbol1[,symbol2,symbol3,…] Requires global entries
```

Here's how the option is set in the IDE:
[image]

And since M.M asked how do I unit test functions which are not called by the rest of the code, here's a screenshot of my debugger. Basically, it stopped the target once the main loop was reached, created an artificial stack frame for a function and called it.
[image]

Comment: Linker options should have (at least on ARM version) also "Input" tab, which has "Keep symbols" textbox. This should be equivalent of your second option.

Comment: @user694733 ARM platform has better support in terms of tools. My IDE doesn't have a "Keep symbols" textbox (or "Input" tab, for that matter). Anyway, unless there is an option to keep ALL the symbols in the output, there's no practical difference in how to list the symbols I want to keep.

Comment: Just for reference: IAR Tech Note 51348 - "Linker removes functions and variables or external not found"